# When and where is the earliest possibility to receive a Mystery gift Pokemon in game?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

On a fresh save (restarted game for example), when and where is the earliest possibility to receive a Pokemon sent to the game via Mystery gift?

It says Pokemon Center, so I'd assume it's the first Pokemon Center you come across, but where is that located?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Mystery Gifts can be picked up at any Pokémon Center and *only* at Pokémon Centers.  Thus, the first chance to pick one up is at the first Pokémon Center, which is in [Santalune City](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Santalune_City).

Answer (score 0):

You can get Mystery Gifts anytime, even right when you begin your journey. You have to wait to get it until you reach Santalune City, but you have to be careful about the level, you will need to have some Gym Badges in order for that Mystery Gift Pokémon to obey your commands.